# Redux-Form Field type number renderField step not working

Tags: numbers, field, redux-form

I am encountering a strange problem when declaring a Field of type number and using the example renderField component on the redux-form website.

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
<div>
<label>{label}</label>
<div>
  <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>
{touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) || (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
</div>
```

);

Inside my render, I have a component of type number with a step size

```
<Field name="SmallStepSizeNumber" type='number' step={0.000001}
                   component={renderField} label="SmallStepSizeNumber"
                   validate={[  ]}
            />
```

All I'm trying to replicate is a normal html step size change, but it just steps by 1 ignoring my step size. The same happens when I try to set min/max/etc. Am I specifying this wrong? Is this a bug?

Answer (score -1):

Passing a string instead of a number might works

```
const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => (
    <div>
      <input type="number" {...input} step="0.1" />
    </div>
);

const Form = () => (
  <Field
    name="foobar"
    component={renderField} 
   />
);
```

Here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/75rh036o/12/